# Error When Uploading an Excel file to GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am developing a system where it should upload an Excel file to a GridView and the  GridView items will be saved to a SQL table with a button click. I did the whole thing and executed in localhost without any error. But when I upload the system to the server, there is an error when I am going to upload an Excel file to the GridView. 
Below is the error I got in try catch exception.

> FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode) at System.Web.HttpPostedFile.SaveAs(String filename) at StyleOperations.Operations.uploadLinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

I created the folder `Uploads` in the server and tried. But still, I am getting the same error. Below I have mentioned my code and Excel File format and can someone please help me. Thank you in advance.

```
 protected void uploadLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string Constr = "";
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(StyleOperationsFileUpload.FileName).ToLower();
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + StyleOperationsFileUpload.FileName);
            StyleOperationsFileUpload.SaveAs(path);
            if (ext.Trim() == ".xls")
            {
                Constr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
            }
            else if (ext.Trim() == ".xlsx")
            {
                Constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
            }
            string query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(Constr);
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            UploadGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            UploadGridView.DataBind();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Please Restart the system')</script>" + ex);
        }
    }
```

Excel file format is as bellow. The same format will be the format of the GridView.

```
| 1 |DESCRIPTION|  SMV   |SEQ NO
| 2 |   Des1    |  1.2   | 1
| 3 |   Des2    |  2.5   | 2
| 4 |   Des3    |  5.8   | 3
| 5 |   Des4    |  4.2   | 4
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the use of following code

```
StyleOperationsFileUpload.SaveAs(path); //don't think it has any thing to do with this one
```

Note: You have hardcoded sheet name to Sheet1$ which i think should be dynamic

Comment: That is not the problem. Usually, when an Excel file is being uploaded to the grid view, the system saves a copy in the server and saved copy's data will be shown in GridView. The problem is, the system does not keep a copy in the server. Therefore it gives above error. Do you have a solution for that @uttam ?

Comment: What is the use of save in server if you can directly import data from excel and dump it into GridView.

Comment: Yes, That is what I also thought. But the application does not allow it. It asks to keep a copy in the server.